# Identify the protocol version in asp.net to serve css depending on HTTP or HTTP/2

Tags: asp.net, http2

Is there any way to identify if a client accept HTTP/2 in asp.net 4.6+? The idea is to be able to send css/js in multiple files instead of bundles?

Request.Params["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] is always saying HTTP/1.1 even though Edge developer tools says HTTP/2

Comment: does your server support it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect HTTP2/SPDY Support in Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211134/detect-http2-spdy-support-in-browser)

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes it does. I am hoping it is possible to read a property somewhere on the Request that tells if it is HTTP or HTTP/2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211134/detect-http2-spdy-support-in-browser is not the same, the question there is client side, this is server side in asp.net.